# SQL select values sum by same ID

Tags: sql, sum

here is my table called "Employee"

```
eID  | name | 
==============
 1   | Mike |  
 2   | Josh |  
 3   | Mike |
```

And table called "Sells"

```
sID  | eID |   | price |
=========================
 1    | 1 |      | 8 |
 2    | 3 |      | 9 |
 3    | 3 |      | 5 |
 4    | 1 |      | 4 |
 5    | 1 |      | 3 |
```

This should be my expected result: returns the total income per employee

```
name   | Income | 
==================
 Mike    | 15 |  
 Josh    | 0 |  
 Mike    | 14 |
```

Actually, I know use the query "SUM...GROUP BY..." to get the incomes of 15 and 14, but I don't know how to get the income of 0 which is not shown on the "Sells" table.

Could someone give me some help? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hint:  `LEFT JOIN`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use a left outer join, so you can get the sum for missing values too. You could use case expression to deal with null values

```
SELECT e.name,
       COALESCE(SUM(price), 0) as Income
  FROM employees e
 LEFT OUTER JOIN sells s
    ON e.eid = s.eid
 GROUP BY e.eid, e.name
```

**Edited:** case expression is not needed. I put coalesce on the return of sum fuction, in order to deal with missing values (SUM over an empty set returns NULL)

Comment: Case _expression_. However, I'd do `sum(coalesce(price, 0))` to save some typing. (Or just `sum(price)` and get a warning if null values appear.)

Comment: @jarlh good point, thank you. As for the case, I would normally use NVL in Oracle. I used case now just to be sure it would work with other databases too

Comment: You can use `COALESCE()` in Oracle too, which is ANSI SQL and portable!